# add flurry to android app using Android studio

Tags: android, flurry

This is Not a duplicate
I've read each post, and at the flurry site as well...

I have read:

> 1. Add the FlurryAnalytics_x.y.z.jar to your classpath
>
>    If you're using Eclipse, modify your Java Build Path, and choose Add External JAR.
>      If you're using the SDK tools directly, drop it into your libs folder and the ant task will pick it up.

I am not using eclipse. 
I am not using SDK tools (as best i know). 
I AM using android studio...
I am not new to this, but i cant seem to get past the particularities of android studio .. so. 
I already have the code added, so i dont need that.
What i need is a step by step on adding the jar file(s), and what "config/build" files that need to be modified....

BWT
if i have a TOP folder MyTestProject, and under that is MyTest, and under that there are build, and source, where Exactly  do i put the libs dir ??

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Android Studio, the projects it creates will pick up jars that are placed in the "libs" directory in the module. If you want to add it manually, do so through Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies.